# Batch file when loaded: The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm having problem on batch file! Everytime I run it it it always says this. This is what it said:

```
the syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

And this is the rest of the code. And I'm trying to do my own code. Like opening a notepad but except not in graphical interference. Can you guys help me?

```
set /p ans= New files or saved file! n or a :

if [%ans%] = [n] (
    set /p mkfl= Files you want to save in! [filename].[bat;cmd;txt] :
    set /p val= Enter Key to Save!:
    echo %val% > %mkfl%
    SET /p t= y:
) else if [%ans%] equ [a] (
    set /p flnm= Type in the filename!:
    set /p val= Type in words!
    set /p ans= Enter [s,o] to re-save or overwrite!:

    if [%ans%] equ [s] (
        ECHO append
    ) else if [%ans%] equ [o] (
        ECHO overwrite
    ) else (
        ECHO problem!
    )

    SET /p z= f:
) else (
    ECHO problem occurred during executing!
    SET /p a= p:
)

set /p fk= .
```

Comment: Read the help for the `IF` command.  Next time troubleshoot by opening a cmd prompt first and then running your batch file by typing the batch file name at the cmd prompt.

Comment: sry, i'm new to cmd.

Comment: thanks a lot #Squashman ! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is at the following statement

```
echo %val% > %mkfl%
```

To solve it, you need to `search` SO (use the facility in the top bar) for `delayed expansion`.

Essentially, since `mkfl` is not defined at the time the `if` statement is reached, the statement is evaluated to `echo  >` which is invalid syntax. The items discussing `delayed expansion` should indicate how to overcome this.

Comment: The mentioned statement supposedly evaluates even to `echo >`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code (for instance using  =  or  equ  instead of  ==   in IF statements).  Below is a modified version that at least runs... though it may not do what you want it to, it might get you started.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p ans= New files or saved file n or a :
if [%ans%] == [n] (
  set /p mkfl= Files you want to save in [filename].[bat;cmd;txt] :
  set /p val= Enter Key to Save:
  echo %val% > !mkfl!
  SET /p t= y:
) else if [%ans%] == [a] (
  set /p flnm= Type in the filename:
  set /p val= Type in words:
  set /p ans= Enter [s,o] to re-save or overwrite:
  if [%ans%] == [s] (
    ECHO append
  ) else if [%ans%] equ [o] (
    ECHO overwrite
  ) else (
    ECHO problem
  )
  SET /p z= f:
) else (
  ECHO problem occurred during executing
  SET /p a= p:
)
set /p fk= .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a little difficulty trying to determine your intended scenarios, but have taken a best guess in the untested rewrite below:

```bat
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET/P "ansone= New files or saved file! n or a: "
IF /I "%ansone%"=="n" (
    SET/P "mkfl= Files you want to save in! [filename].[bat;cmd;txt]: "
    SET/P "valone= Enter Key to Save!: "
    >"!mkfl!" ECHO !valone!
    SET/P "t= y: "
) ELSE (
    IF /I "%ansone%"=="a" (
        SET/P "flnm= Type in the filename!: "
        SET/P "valone= Type in words! "
        SET/P "anstwo= Enter [s,o] to re-save or overwrite!: "
        IF /I "!anstwo!"=="s" (
            ECHO append
        ) ELSE (
            IF /I "!anstwo!"=="o" (
                ECHO overwrite
            ) ELSE (
                ECHO problem!
            )
        )
        SET/P "z= f: "
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO problem occurred during executing!
        SET/P "a= p: "
    )
)
SET/P "fk= . "
```

*I am assuming you alone know the intention of the prompted setting of `%t%`,`%z%`, `%a%` & `%fk%` so have left those as per your original script.*